# Get the extension of a file but can't get the filename

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, web

I am trying to check if a file has a valid extension or not. The problem is that when I give the file a random extension like `.txt` it doesn't get caught.

I think the problem is that I am not actually getting the full filename.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getExtension(fileName) 
    {
        var parts = fileName.split('.');
        return parts[parts.length - 1];
    }

    function isVideo(fileName) 
    {
        var ext = getExtension(fileName);

        switch (ext.toLowerCase()) 
        {
            case 'mp4': return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    function check()
    {
        var f = document.getElementsByID('file');

        if(isVideo(f.value) && document.getElementById('file').value)
        {
            return true;
        }

        document.getElementById('errMsg').style.display = '';

        return false;
    }

</script>
```

The PHP form:

```
<?php
$nexturl = "http://localhost/index.php"; 
?>

<form action="<?php echo($response->url); ?>?nexturl=<?php echo(urlencode($nexturl)); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return check();">
  <input id="file" type="file" name="file"/>
  <div id="errMsg" style="display:none;color:red">
    Bad file type.
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo($response->token); ?>"/>
  <input type="submit" value="go" />

</form>
</php>
```

Comment: you got a typo at `var f = document.getElementsByID('file');`

Comment: @Jeff what is the typo? I don't see it.

Comment: `getElementSByiD` needs to be singular (as id's are unique) and the D has to be lower case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first obtain the file extension and then do what you need to with it:

```
var patt1 = /\.[0-9a-z]+$/i;
var fileName = "file.zip";
var theReturn = fileName.match(patt1);
alert(theReturn); //returns .zip
```

So, in your code, you would need to switch your `switch` statement to the following:

```
function isVideo(fileName) 
{
    var patt1 = /\.[0-9a-z]+$/i;
    var fileName = "file.zip";
    var theReturn = fileName.match(patt1);

    switch (theReturn.toLowerCase()) 
    {
        case '.mp4': return true; //make sure it's .mp4 instead of just mp4
    }
    retrun false
}
```

**EDIT**

Example to get file name and extension of uploaded file to FileUpload control:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE Html />
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="File1" type="file" />
        <input type="button" id="btnGetExt" value="Get File Extension"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="theJS.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
btnGetExt.onclick = function () {
    var patt1 = /\.[0-9a-z]+$/i;
    var fileName = document.getElementById('File1').value;
    alert(fileName);
    var theReturn = fileName.match(patt1);
    alert(theReturn);
}
```

Comment: The file is given to me in PHP I believe it is why I have to find it by using this: `document.getElementsByID('file')`

Comment: What type of element is 'file'

Comment: I have added it above, please look at the PHP code.

Comment: I added an example that should give you what you need. It looks like you're element is an `input` with the type `file` so the above code should work. I'm not sure when you want to trigger all the code so I just used a button click in my example.

Comment: `/\.[0-9a-z]+$/i` assumes a file extension contains only this very limited set of characters. Really, you want everything that is not another dot: `/\.[^.]+$/`

Comment: This is just a basic example. If you need a regular expression that covers other formats, there is plenty of stuff out there. You should be able to just replace the regex with the one that fits your needs.